# Is <BUTTON> functionally equivalent to <SPAN>?

Tags: html, css, button

It seems to me that `<button>` in HTML5 is essentially a `<span>` with some default styling and possibly slightly different DTD rules... (You can't have a `<button>` in a `<button>` or?)

Is my understanding correct? And other than for declarative purposes and default styling, is there any reason to use the `<button>` tag anymore?

Comment: If you want to have… an… interactive… *button*… perhaps? Instead of plain text?

Comment: A `button` can be used to submit a form without any additional modifications.

Comment: And a button can be used to close my shirt whilst a span is completely useless for that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

- A button will be focusable by default
- A button will be announced as an interactive control by screen readers
- A button will submit a form it is inside (or one it isn't with a `form` attribute, other attributes can do things like change the form's action)
- A button can be given a name and value to submit extra data when it is used to submit a form

---

Remember: HTML is, at its heart, a language used to describe what content is. The CSS specification even has [a warning about replacing meaningful HTML elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) with generic ones like div and span:

> Note. CSS gives so much power to the "class" attribute, that authors could conceivably design their own "document language" based on elements with almost no associated presentation (such as DIV and SPAN in HTML) and assigning style information through the "class" attribute. Authors should avoid this practice since the structural elements of a document language often have recognized and accepted meanings and author-defined classes may not.

Comment: I never knew you could add a `form` attribute to a button outside of a form. Nice to know there are still useful things about HTML5 I can learn.

Comment: I wish the first thing that people learn about using HTML in general was a link to the W3C specification. It's a long read but it really helps to understand.

Answer (score 1):

A `<button>` in essence is a tag used to denote that the component being processed is used for interactions with the user.

The buttons are part of the `form` paging system. Also, web bots can only interact with clickable buttons. If a span is clickable a web bot won't know and your referencing will suffer it (if the span replaces a button).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you get at a button being a span, or even vice versa but let's be clear on what each of them are first:

**[Span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)**

The `<span>` tag is used to group inline-elements in a document. It provides no visual change by itself; finally it provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a part of a document.

**[Button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)**

As you can see, a `button` is so much more than a `span` tag. Please consider a read through the official docs.